# Database design for user experiences with various specialities

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

I’m doing a database design for user experience with specialties. A user can have experience months/ years for each specialty ( please see the attached images)
I’m planning to create a table to list all specialities, and a table to list experiences within years, and another table to list experiences with in months, and finally another table that will basically say “this user has this number of years / months experience for this speciality”

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

but having a table for experience is months and another table for experience in years kinda sounds redundant, but I can’t think of another way to do it. Is my design fine ?

Comment: Either store all experience in months, or have a column of units (months/years)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'or have a columns of units ( months/years) , could you please provide a graphical example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
User_ID Skill_ID Experience unit 
1.       101        7.      Year
1.       102.       4.      Month
2.       101.       9.      Month
```

Comment: I think this would do the job:

User_ID Skill_ID Experience unit 
1.       101        1-2.      Year
2.       102.       1-3.      Month
3.       101.       9.      Month
4.       104        5+.      Year
5        105        6 Month

Comment: If I was doing that then I'd store the ranges in a separate table with a surrogate id, and arranging them by shortest to greatest, and then store that id in the table you describe above.

Comment: hehe I've implemented it like I explained on my previous comment, what problems could it possibly give me in future if I leave it as it is ?

Comment: It's just a cumbersome and inefficient way to sort people according to experience.

Comment: aaaw I see, one last question...

I’m trying to  get all specialities , join the candidate experience  table on speciality_id =  speciality_id on the candidate table, and also join the documents table on document id = document on the candidate experience id  for an active candidate…

I’m expecting all specialties from the specialties table, and all the columns from the joined table. If a candidate has no experience for a specific specialty, I expect to get a null for the experience field in the experiences table. I get an empty array RN

Comment: This is my query:  $candiate_experiences = DB::table('specialities')
        ->LeftJoin('candidate_experiences', 'candidate_experiences.speciality_id', '=', 'specialities.id')
        ->LeftJoin('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'candidate_experiences.document_id')
        ->LeftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=',  $candidate->id)
        ->get();

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question, referencing this one

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a table `candidate_experience` which has the following columns :

- `candidate_id` which indicates the id of the candidate
- `specialty` indicates the name of the specialty
- `in_years` indicates the number of experience in years
- `in_months` indicates the number of experience in months

You can just make a single table. Without the need to do 4 separate tables.

**P.S**: You may need to make a composite primary key `(candidate_id , specialty)` to avoid duplication of same specialty for the same candidate.

^^ This is of course if you are sure that there is no multiple specialties with the same name. Else, you can make a separate specialties table as you did and replace `specialty` with the `specialty_id` in the `candidate_experience` table